# mobile web app design - is it still advisable to use image sprites?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Im currently working on a mobile web app and am wondering if I should use individual images or continue with using image sprites like I would for my desktop site? Im just worried about the increased file size from combining all the images and how this could have an effect on the load time of my pages?

Kyle

Comment: I'd continue to use sprites, _especially_ for a mobile app. One http request is better than lots, and most mobiles these days can handle it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using a sprite set, just bear in mind that if you target the app for iPhones, they will only cache files under 25kB in size. So, if your image grows too much, it would, paradoxically, be a better idea to split it into separate images. This will account for more HTTP requests on the first run of the app - but will not generate the additional HTTP request continuously with each subsequent page load, saving both your and the iPhone user's bandwidth :). Oh, same applies for JavaScript and CSS files :).

Answer (score 1):

Sprites work just fine on the vast majority of phones (barring older Nokia Series 40, BlackBerry pre v. 6.0 and any legacy devices (anything without a full HTML 4.01 browser).

What you should be aware of is that if you are using a flexible/responsive layout with primarily flexible units, it can be very hard to properly position the sprites while retaining the flexibility in the layout.